# Entering value in one field & leaving the other empty in php get the wrong result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, between

I have total 5 Fields in search but the two (pages and written_year) have from-to values. And the value for both will be selected using option tag. 
 
Now, it is working fine, but if someone just enter the value for "From" or "To" and leave the other field empty, how can search for it? 
 
In Pages Min value is "1" and max value is "99" 
 
In Year Min value is "1990" and max value is "2017" 
 
See the below code which i am now using and it show me the complete result while it need to search between two numbers. 
 
**PHP & SQL FOR BOTH FIELDS**

```
<?php
if(empty($_GET['search'])){

$search_keywords=$_SESSION['academic_keyword']=$_GET['academic_keyword'];

if(isset($_GET['page_from']) && $_GET['page_from']!='From'){
    $search_page_from=$_GET['page_from'];
}
else{   
    $search_page_from_null='1';
    $search_page_from = '1';
}

if(isset($_GET['page_to']) && $_GET['page_to']!='To'){
    $search_page_to=$_GET['page_to'];
}
else{   
    $search_page_to_null='99';
    $search_page_to = '99'; 
}

if(isset($_GET['written_year_from']) && $_GET['written_year_from']!='From'){
    $search_written_year_from=$_GET['written_year_from'];
}
else{   
    $search_written_year_from_null='2017';
    $search_written_year_from = '2017';
}

if(isset($_GET['written_year_to']) && $_GET['written_year_to']!='To'){
    $search_written_year_to=$_GET['written_year_to'];
}
else{   
    $search_written_year_to_null='1990';
    $search_written_year_to = '1990';
}

$search_price_to=$_GET['price_to'];
$search_work_id=$_GET['work_id'];

$current_year = date("Y");

if($search_page_from!='From' && $search_page_to=='99'){
    $get_products="select *, LOCATE('$search_keywords',keywords3) AS keyword from academic_work where
    (title like '%$search_keywords%' OR short_description like '%$search_keywords%' OR long_description like '%$search_keywords%') OR
    (pages BETWEEN '$search_page_from' AND '$search_page_to') OR
    (price BETWEEN '1' AND '$search_price_to') OR
    (YEAR(written_year) BETWEEN '$search_written_year_from' AND '$search_written_year_to') OR 
    (academic_work_id like '$search_work_id')
    ORDER BY keyword ASC";
}

else if($search_page_from=='1' && $search_page_to!='To'){
    $get_products="select *, LOCATE('$search_keywords',keywords3) AS keyword from academic_work where
    (title like '%$search_keywords%' OR short_description like '%$search_keywords%' OR long_description like '%$search_keywords%') OR
    (pages BETWEEN '$search_page_from' AND '$search_page_to') OR
    (price BETWEEN '1' AND '$search_price_to') OR
    (YEAR(written_year) BETWEEN '$search_written_year_from' AND '$search_written_year_to') OR 
    (academic_work_id like '$search_work_id')
    ORDER BY keyword ASC";
}

else if($search_written_year_from!='From' && $search_written_year_to_null=='1990'){
    $get_products="select *, LOCATE('$search_keywords',keywords3) AS keyword from academic_work where
    (title like '%$search_keywords%' OR short_description like '%$search_keywords%' OR long_description like '%$search_keywords%') OR
    (pages BETWEEN '$search_page_from' AND '$search_page_to') OR
    (price BETWEEN '1' AND '$search_price_to') OR
    (YEAR(written_year) BETWEEN '$search_written_year_from' AND '$search_written_year_to_null') OR 
    (academic_work_id like '$search_work_id')
    ORDER BY keyword ASC";
}

else if($search_written_year_from_null=='2017' && $search_written_year_to!='To'){
    $get_products="select *, LOCATE('$search_keywords',keywords3) AS keyword from academic_work where
    (title like '%$search_keywords%' OR short_description like '%$search_keywords%' OR long_description like '%$search_keywords%') OR
    (pages BETWEEN '$search_page_from' AND '$search_page_to') OR
    (price BETWEEN '1' AND '$search_price_to') OR
    (YEAR(written_year) BETWEEN '$search_written_year_from_null' AND '$search_written_year_to') OR 
    (academic_work_id like '$search_work_id')
    ORDER BY keyword ASC";
}
```

**Thanks in Advance :)**

Comment: Change the variables names :$search_page_from_null, $search_page_to_null so you'd remove the _null part.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Same Issue.. i tried every single thing..

Comment: What do you mean "same issue", what's going wrong?

Comment: i get the complete records i have in this table

Comment: Use `empty()` instead of `isset()`. The latter will always return true, even if the field is empty as it only checks if it's set. Not if there's actually a value in it. On form submit, those are _always_ set. `empty()` will check if they are set, but also if there's a value in it.

Comment: also there if(isset($_GET['search']))

Answer (score 0):

There you were assigning for two different variables in if else conditions and in SELECT query you are using that two variables right. so My point, in if else condition any one of part would be executed so from that two variables any one of them should be assigned but you are using that two variables in SELECT query.

This you have to fix based on your need.
Sample SUGGESTION code.

```
if(isset($_GET['written_year_from']) && $_GET['written_year_from']!='From'){
    $search_written_year_from=$_GET['written_year_from'];
}
else{   
    $search_written_year_from_null='1990';
    $search_written_year_from = '1990'; // using this variable in page_from conditions 
}
```

Repeat this for all conditions. Hope It helps.

Comment: Yes, this code is good but i face two issues one is that from is working but to is not working? and if u select the value between 2 and 5, it will show you records having pages between 2 and 5 and also the records pages starting from 2 like 20, 200, 22 ?

Comment: That would come under other criteria like "academic_work_id like '$search_work_id'". This is based on your record and it retrieve the data. What is academic _work_id for records pages starting from 2 like 20, 200, 22....

Comment: Ok.. and what about "to" is not working and also "from" for the "year" gives me wrong records?

Comment: code is updated with your suggestion... check the code, and if u help me to find issue?

Comment: Your code looks fine, Can you give sample records that have all possibility and tell the criteria for search. or create personal chat room

Comment: to join [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158474/web-tec)

Comment: i click on "chat room", but they say "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq."